# what is the Snowflake query engine that is used to query the data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Please find the below program

```
select date_trunc('hour', starttime) as "date",
    count(*) as "num trips",
    avg(tripduration)/60 as "avg duration (mins)", 
    avg(haversine(start_station_latitude, start_station_longitude, end_station_latitude, end_station_longitude)) as "avg distance (km)" 
    from trips
    group by 1 order by 1;
```

Comment: Always explain your code what are you writing for ??

Comment: I want to know how the quires are proceed in Snowflake , ex like hive we have MR Engine   , like that for Snowflake which engine is used to process records

Answer (score 0):

The Snowflake data warehouse uses a new SQL database engine with a unique architecture designed for the cloud.

Comment: Can you explain what is the new SQL database engine with a unique architecture designed for the cloud.